# Reputation Graph Range Selector Bug

Tags: bug, reputation-history

I noticed this bug (or at least what I think is a bug) when viewing a user's reputation graph. I tried it on my own reputation graph and was able to reproduce the issue as well. At the bottom of the graph, when attempting to use the data range selector, the highlighted portion always starts over on the second click.

[image]

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Navigate to the *Reputation* tab.
2. Once the tab is active, select the *Graph* option in the upper right.
3. In the range selector below the graph click once anywhere.
4. Move your mouse left or right. The dark gray manual selection box appears highlighting the relevant portion of the reputation graph that you want to view (See screenshot).
5. Click again to confirm your selection.

The bug occurs on the second click used to confirm the selection. Instead of confirming the selected range and modifying the graph to represent this range, the second click removes the previously highlighted portion and starts a new selection range.

I may be doing something wrong, but I've tried both clicking once and then again, double clicking each time, left and right clicking and click, hold, drag and release. None of these methods appear to work.