# Reputation Graph Range Selector Bug on touch capable computers

Tags: bug, reputation-history, google-chrome, reputation-graph

Possibly related: [Reputation Graph Range Selector Bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317915/reputation-graph-range-selector-bug)

I found that when using Chrome, the reputation history range selector did not work at all.  I could start the selection but never finish it.  I was mystified that I did not see many mentions of this on meta.

After an hour of debug, I traced this to the fact that my laptop is touch-capable, which means that Chrome defaults to sending touch and mouse events.  There was a bug in Highcharts in which it ignored mouse events in some cases when touch events were present.

Searching the Highcharts GitHub, I found this issue:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6457#issuecomment-290403538

Of course, the version of Highcharts that StackExchange uses seems very old, so the bug may be different.  Upgrading the version in any case should resolve the issue.

As a workaround for any affected users, you can go to chrome://flags and change "Touch Events API" from "Automatic" to "Disabled".  This of course prevents you from using touch in Chrome, but in many cases like mine I am usually docking my laptop so touch is not an issue anyway.

Comment: It never occurred to me that it's related to the touch capability of the device. At least this explains why it's working on my desktop, but not on my touch-notebook... Hopefully this will be fixed sometime. I've seen so many reports about this on meta, but most are closed as [status-norepro]...

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Reputation graph not interactable with a touch screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279173/164356).

Comment: Ah, I didn't check meta.stackexchange.  How does this get bumped so it gets attention now that a fix is known?

Comment: They should seriously be using `D3` for this, makes me sad that it's not using OS :(

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce this **only** in Chrome. On my Windows 10 touch-capable laptop, click-and-drag with the mouse works fine in IE and Edge (didn't bother trying in Firefox, Opera, etc.). And in Chrome, it's worse than described above: click-and-drag doesn't even select anything on the lower timeline, never mind get as far as the upper timeline not refreshing to match the selection.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, yes, it is specific to which events are sent by which browser.  Chrome seems to send both noise and touch events, which causes this problem in high charts.  I have seen similar issues on other sites, which finally made sense when I debugged this.

Comment: * auto-correct correction:  noise=>mouse